# Forcing Responsive Bootstrap Horizontal Cards into Vertical Cards at larger viewports

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am experimenting with Bootstrap 4 cards and their responsive behaviors. My goal is to have two Horizontal Bootstrap Cards stacked horizontally, only to collapse into Vertical Cards are smaller viewport sizes for Mobile screen compatibility. While I am able to achieve this using standard bootstrap code, the Cards first shrink in size to match the decreasing viewport, off-centering my picture, before turning into vertical cards. Is there anyway I can make force the Horizontal Cards into the Vertical Card styling at a larger viewport?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card-deck justify-content-center">
                <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 740px;">
                  <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="https://devshift.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/profile-icon-png-898.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">NAME</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><b>From</b>: LOCATION<br><br></p>
                        <p class="card-text">ROLES, DESCRIPTION</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 740px;">
                  <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="https://devshift.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/profile-icon-png-898.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">NAME</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><b>From</b>: LOCATION<br><br></p>
                        <p class="card-text">ROLES, DESCRIPTION</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note these are taken directly from the Bootstrap Documentation on Cards found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-groups).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>BOOTSTRAP CARD TEST</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <!-- DOCUMENT/CODE LINKS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b60e607f25.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-deck justify-content-center">
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 740px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://devshift.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/profile-icon-png-898.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">NAME</h5>
              <p class="card-text"><b>From</b>: LOCATION<br><br></p>
              <p class="card-text">ROLES, DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 740px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://devshift.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/profile-icon-png-898.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">NAME</h5>
              <p class="card-text"><b>From</b>: LOCATION<br><br></p>
              <p class="card-text">ROLES, DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@satanshu-mishra - **TL;DR:** Use Bootstrap display classes on the card-img-top for vertical display (**d-block d-sm-none**) and a separate DIV used for horizontal display (**d-none d-sm-block**) to control the responsive image swap.

The documentation for horizontal cards in Bootstrap 4.3 wasn't as helpful for the responsive effect I wanted to create. I was able to create a similar effect with Bootstrap display classes for the card-img-top element in the vertical position at the default (xs) screen width and for the card image as a background image of a DIV in the horizontal position:

*(NOTE: I'm using Ruby on Rails Active Storage for the card image and a transparent spacer image emitted from Webpack to enable the background image effect in horizontal orientation. You should be able to replace the code in <%= %> brackets with standard HTML image tags)*

```
<div class="card col-12">
    <%= image_tag(artist.avatar, class: 'card-img-top d-block d-sm-none') %>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class='col-4 d-none d-sm-block' style='overflow:hidden; background: url(<%= url_for(artist.avatar) %>);background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: auto 100%;'>
            <%= image_pack_tag 'media/stylesheets/images/trans_spacer.png', height: 100 %>
        </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                    <p><!-- CONTENT GOES HERE --></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't been able to create the same effect with a card deck, but I hope this provides a helpful starting point for you.